# Reload a webpage on desktop after android app sends data to php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php webpage which shows qr code after filling a form. My android app scans the qr code and sends the data to the php server to process. The php webpage and the page which process the android request are different. All this works properly.

Now after this I want the desktop page to refresh so that the form and qr code both disappear. How can I do this?

Also should I keep the code which process android request and the form page in the same file or it does not make any difference?

I am a beginner in this please help me. Thank you.

Comment: you either need to poll the webserver for updates or use websockets. This article might help you to get started http://socketo.me/

Comment: You could use a `setInterval` with javascript that would make a request to a PHP page that tells the Js when the QR code was scanned or not and then reload the page. Or WebSockets, but I think that'd be a bit overkill and could put a huge stress on your infrastructure (for example if the client never scanned the QR code).

Comment: @GGG you can open the websocket in a specific part of the page, which is only shown if the user wants to scan the qr code (e.g. he klicks a show qr code button) and close the connection when the scan is done or after a timeout (e.g. 30 seconds)

Comment: @r3bel Yeah, that does make sense, you're right

Comment: @GGG how can I know when my qr code is scanned? Also thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: @ShreyamShah If you use WebSockets you can use the app to notify the server which will in turn notify the browser almost instantly, otherwise you can store the state of the QR code scanning on a database and have a Js script check the database periodically to see if the QR code was scanned or not.